# Facebook embedded post capture See more click

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need help with fb embedded posts. When I embed long posts which have 'See more' option and in case of clicking on it my wrapping div doesn't change the height. Is it possible to subscribe to some event to capture this click? I see that FB js sdk has some Arbiter class and in js code i see that when See more is clicked the Arbiter.inform('reflow') is called. Can I subscribe to Arbiter.inform somehow? Or can I capture See more (expand) click event in other way?